# Setting new thumb in SeekBar removes progress background

Tags: android, seekbar

I would like to know, is this behaviour normal? Because I didn't find any document where describes that when you set a new drawable of SeekBar's thumb, you should also set a new drawable of progress.

Comment: well,i have worked with seekbar and i don't think,you should see such behavior when you set new thumb image. can you post your xml code?

Comment: I set it using, Java code. I becomes to understand that the problem would be related with a format of drawable's image, I set .png as thumb

Comment: nope.it is not a problem.png image works fine as thumb drawable. I can't figure out until you post your xml.

Comment: I repeat myself - I set thumb, using Java Code. I just thought, that thumb should be translucent and shows the bar behind it.

Comment: it works in my case but yes,other attributes might matter.

Comment: I found my mistake right know - size of new thumb is too huge, so it hides progress background